# Automated deployment options for SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been tasked to look into ways to automate the deployment process for our SSRS 2012 reports.  Are there any good tools out there?  I'm thinking of something along the lines of press a button and the report gets deployed.

Thanks!

Comment: You can deploy reports from within Visual Studio (SSDT), which has the advantage of being able to use the solution/project configurations to deploy to multiple target environment (e.g. Dev, UAT). This can be done through a simple right-click, "Deploy" action. Can you explain why you are looking for another option?

Comment: I am trying to minimize what the operations staff will have to do to deploy reports.  Our organization does not want developers deploying to the production servers and I want to minimize the chance of deployment errors.

Answer (score 21):

To deploy our SSRS reports, we're using this lovely powershell project:

https://github.com/timabell/ssrs-powershell-deploy

Usage:

```
.\Deploy-SSRSProject.ps1 -path YourReportsProject.rptproj -configuration Release -verbose

or you can use the alternate parameter set:

.\Deploy-SSRSProject\Deploy-SSRSProject.ps1 -path .\AFS.Reports.rptproj -ServerUrl http://localhost/Reportserver -Folder MyReports -DataSourceFolder "MyReports/Data Sources" -DataSetFolder "MyReports/Datasets" -verbose
```

The full deployment story (for us):

- `ssrs-powershell-deploy` scripts, .rptproj, .rds, .rdl files are all packaged into a nuget package by our build server.
- [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) extracts the nuget package on our SSRS server and calls `Deploy-SSRSProject.ps1`

Comment: This is hugely helpful - thank you. Have you noticed a speed difference between deploying through this method and deploying through VS? We have a solution with about 50 datasets and over 175 reports. Deploying through VS takes ~ 5-10 minutes - using this script is nearly an hour. It's not a big deal - I'll just schedule the Octopus deployments for the evening, but was just wondering if you saw that too.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped! No I haven't noticed that. We don't have as many reports as that, though (about 20).

Comment: Well you totally get an upvote from me :-) glad you found it useful. Interesting to hear of the extra layers you have, haven't had the chance to use octopus myself yet.

Comment: @edgesrazor do go ahead and raise a bug on the issue tracker for the project, not promising anything but it's good to collate this kind of information. I've never deployed anything without the script so I wouldn't know the difference.

Comment: It's most likely due to Get-Content. Try replacing 
$RawDefinition = Get-Content -Encoding Byte -Path $RsdPath with
$RawDefinition = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($RsdPath).

Answer (score 7):

### Visual Studio Deployment

Visual Studio is actually really good at automatic deployment. I've used it a number of times with great results. You need to split your solution into separate projects for each folder on the report server and then it will take a bit of time to configure each project & deployment environment. But after that initial time investment it works wonders and when you add a new project you can simply copy the deployment settings for an existing project.

MSDN article: [Set Deployment Properties (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155802.aspx)

### Rs.exe Utility

Alternatively you can use the Rs.exe utility which comes with SSRS. It is a command-line utility used for automatic deployment and administration. I haven't personally use this one, but I know of it. It is my understanding that there are also third party utilities which leverage Rs.exe in order to automate report deployment but I haven't used any of them so I can't recommend any.

More info on MSDN: [RS.exe Utility (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx)

---

I'm sure there are also other third-party tools you could get but I haven't ever looked into them. I've always found the Visual Studio deployment functionality sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using devenv which is located in:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`. The ... 10.0 folder is based on the version no. of your Visual Studio so I have only used this version so cannot vouch for anything else. If you view the help /? commandline switch you can see there are options to build and/or deploy a solution.
In brief I used: `devenv {solutionfile} /Deploy {configuration} /Project {projectname}`.

I did not use any deployment software but I did know how to code in C#.NET so pays to be familiar with System.IO and System.Xml name spaces.

Given the requirement deploy any file (so reports, datasets or datasources) that has been modified within the past 2 week sprint.

So basically my .net code worked as follows (NB: there are ares that you might have to consider first how well do you know how solution and project files work and if you have more than 1 platform - a platform for the uninitiated is a different set of project build and deployment settings):

1. Read the sln file line by line to get list of projects for the specific platform that are ready to be built/deployed, for simplicity my code assumed only one platform and all projects were to be deployed
2. The list from 1 gives me the `subproject\subproject.rptproj` settings in which I can break on the backslash to get the subfolder name from which I can iterate over all files in the project folder and check each file for the LastWritten datetime stamp of the file to determine what files that need to be deployed.
3. I back-up the entire file (declaration and contents)
4. If a file has not changed I edit the project file on the fly using xml and remove all unwanted files (ProjectItem's) not to be deployed
5. If there are dataset or datasource files changed then I also edit the respective configuration section of the project file and modify the particular configuration section accordingly
6. Run my build solution process i.e. devenv with commandline args (FYI: I did not encounter any .NET exceptions in this step)
7. Restore my project file

Providing your SSRS solution is configured correctly and the person running the .net commandline solution has permissions to deploy all should be well. Was easy enough to share my commandline solution source code to anyone else in my team to run to avoid having to white-list the exe if your company has employed such restrictions.