# Build once Deploy everywhere on SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, jenkins, ssrs-2008

I am initiating a huge team to use SSRS for their reporting purposes. Previously I used to develop the reports and send it across to the DBA to implement it, but my recent posting is into a company where they Build once and deploy many process.

I would like to know how reports I developed on DEV environment be pushed into the upper environments with an automated build process.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automated deployment options for SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002197/automated-deployment-options-for-ssrs)

Comment: Top links on google for automation of SSRS deployment: [this blog](http://www.sqlblogspot.com/2014/03/ssrs-deploymentcomplete-automation2012.html) and [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/WTFNext/archive/2012/03/31/automated-ssrs-deployment-with-the-rs-utility-again.aspx)

Comment: As it currently stands, this question doesn't really demonstrate any effort with regard to what possible solutions you've searched for and read about already. The first of the two blog links that I posted discusses pros and cons of several approaches. If you're looking for a community consensus on what the best/easiest way is, you'll want to list options. Even then, you're bordering on opinion-based question, so be careful.